# glsl vertex shader causes INTCONSTANT error

Tags: opengl, glsl

- opengl 3.0
- glsl 130
- ubuntu 18.04
- intel i7 3520m

I wrate simple vertex shader and fragment shader.

```
#version 130

in vec4 position;

void main(){
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

```
#version 130 

out vec4 fragment;

void main(){
    fragment = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

But the shaders causes errors.

```
Compile Error in vertex shader
0:7(2): error: syntax error, unexpected INTCONSTANT, expecting $end

Compile Error in fragment shader
0:7(2): error: syntax error, unexpected INTCONSTANT, expecting $end
```

Comment: Please add the code that compiles/creates the shader.

Comment: It seems the the shader files are not read correctly. Either the shader code is not 0-terminated after  reading the files or the files are not read at all.

Comment: thank you for comments.
I solved the probrem.

Comment: I think you have too many parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
glShaderSource(shader,count, &string, length);
```

when length is set NULL. the string is null character terminated.
but I wrote ¥0 instead of \0